# OpenSSL RAND_byte issue with iOS Simulator

Tags: iphone, macos, openssl, ios-simulator, ios6.1

I have downloaded the latest source from [**OpenSSL Page**](https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1g.tar.gz) (released on April 7th, 2014), and created a libcrypto.a library using [**Tutorial**](http://www.cvursache.com/2013/08/13/How-To-Build-openssl-For-iOS/) Where i have followed the steps in which i run **./build-openssl.sh** script file to generate libcrypto.a file for all environments (armv7s, armv7, i386) on Mac OS X having version **10.9.2**.

I am able to encrypt / decrypt the date using EVP_aes_256_cbc encryption but my code gets failed when i try to get RAND_byte. The code gets **crashed on RAND_byte** call.

Below are the codes, which i am trying to get the RAND_byte seeds:

// *Code 1*

```
unsigned char seed[32];
RAND_bytes(seed, 32);
```

// *Code 2*

```
int count = 24;
unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *)calloc(count, sizeof(unsigned char));
RAND_bytes(buffer, count);
```

// *Code 3*

```
int count = 24;
unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(int)*count);
RAND_bytes(buffer, count);
```

// *Code 4*

```
int count = 24;
unsigned char *buffer = OPENSSL_malloc(count);
RAND_bytes(buffer, count);
```

When I run above code on iOS 6.0/6.1 Simulator, It gets crashed on RAND_byte call and I get **“_interposition_vtable_unimplemented”** on Thread 1 and no message  get displayed on console.

When I run the same code on iOS 7.0+ Simulator, It gets crashed on RAND_byte call and I get **“__pthread_kill”** on Thread 1 and **“Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone: open$UNIX2003 called from function RAND_poll in image CryptographyTest.”** on Console.

But WHEN I run the same code on iPad with iOS 7.0.4, All above codes runs perfectly. Where i get the return value from RAND_byte is 1.

I don’t understand the behavior that some of the functions does not work on iOS simulator but everything works with iOS devices.

Any help highly appreciated! Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ... using Tutorial where i have followed the steps in which i
> run ./build-openssl.sh script file to generate libcrypto.a file
> for all environments (armv7s, armv7, i386) 
> ...
> I don’t understand the behavior that some of the functions does
> not work on iOS simulator but everything works with iOS devices.
> ```

The script is wrong for your usage:

[image]

Its *not* building for the simulator. Its building for the desktop. This:

```
ARCHS=("armv7s" "armv7" "i386")
SDKS=("iphoneos" "iphoneos" "macosx")
```

Probably needs to be changed to:

```
ARCHS=("armv7s" "armv7" "i386")
SDKS=("iphoneos" "iphoneos" "iPhoneSimulator")
```

With `iPhoneSimulator`, the proper SDK will be used:

```
$ ls /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/
MacOSX.platform         iPhoneSimulator.platform
iPhoneOS.platform
```

Does the project you are using claim its multi-arch and for the iPhone and iPhone Simulator? Or does it claim its multi-arch and for iPhone and OS X?

Comment: Thanks man!! I have came across some issues with that script file.

Answer (score 0):

> and created a libcrypto.a library for iOS use using Tutorial.

I don't know about that Tutorial, but OpenSSL has procedures to build the library for iOS. You can find it in the [FIPS User Guide 2.0](https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf), Appendix E.

You can fetch a prebuilt version of OpenSSL for iOS at [Github](http://github.com/noloader). It was built using the OpenSSL procedures. Its a fat library, and it has i386, ARMv7, ARMv7s and ARM64 architectures.

---

> “__pthread_kill” on Thread 1 and “Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone: open$UNIX2003 called from function RAND_poll in image CryptographyTest.” on Console.

I believe this indicates the OpenSSL library was not built properly for the simulator or devices.

---

> ```
> int count = 24;
> unsigned char *buffer = OPENSSL_malloc(count);
> RAND_bytes(buffer, count);
> ```

Just bike shedding here, but you ignored the return value from `RAND_bytes`. According to the docs on [`RAND_bytes`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RAND_bytes.html):

> RAND_bytes() returns 1 on success, 0 otherwise. The error code can be
>   obtained by ERR_get_error(3).

Silent failures are a kiss of death to high integrity software.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The tutorial is pretty simple, it uses the **./build-openssl.sh** file for building lib, and i have found this script only in most places when googled. If the library is not build properly than how its working perfectly on iPhone and even works on Simulator for **EVP_aes_256_cbc** encryption. And I am not able to check the return value of RAND_byte as code doesn't run further. 
I like the last line of your answer. :]

Comment: The prebuilt version of OpenSSL at github page which you have mentioned is not working as it does not include the engine file.

Comment: This Prebuilt at [Github](https://github.com/sharplet/ios-openssl/tree/be08f44a082515683cdbdb9f6919ce35adbc8d17) gives me a work around for my problem. Still wanted to know the exact issue happened, so waiting for answer...

Comment: @Zeeshan - "... is not working as it does not include the engine file" - what engine are you you using with iOS?

Comment: @Zeeshan - "Still wanted to know the exact issue happened, so waiting for answer" - for that, we'd need to see how you set up your cross-compile environment and the output of `make all`. If that's what you want, you should update your question or risk it being closed for "not enough information".

Comment: I have modified my question.